# Why $(\alpha-1)^{-1}\le u^2$ where $u$ is a fundamental unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and $\alpha=2^{1/3}$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given $\alpha = 2^{1/3},$ I want to show that $\beta = (\alpha-1)^{-1}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and is between 1 and $u^2$, where $u$ is  a fundamental unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. I see why its a unit and why 1 is a lower bound of $\beta$, but I don't see how to get $\beta \le u^2$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "in between"? You litterally mean in the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: This is the exact wording in the book. I think the answer to your question is yes, or at least that's how I understand it.

Comment: Ok, have you found a fundamental unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that you don't yet know that $1 + \alpha + \alpha^2 = \beta$ is the fundamental unit of ${\mathbb Z}[\alpha]$, but that you're busy establishing this.

Presumably, you have some theorem that gives an estimate on the absolute value of the fundamental unit. For instance

**Theorem (Artin's Inequality).** Let $K$ be a real cubic field and let $v \in {\mathcal O}_K^*$ with $v > 1$. Then $|\text{disc}(K)| \leq 4v^3 + 24$.

In your case, applying this to $K = {\mathbb Q}(\alpha)$ and the fundamental unit $u$ of ${\mathbb Z}[\alpha]$ gives $108 \leq 4 u^3 + 24$, so $u^2 \geq (\sqrt[3]{21})^2 \approx 7.61$. Now $\beta \approx 3.85$, so $1 < \beta < u^2$.